# Is it mandatory to store OTP in database?

Tags: java, spring

I am writing web application in java.I have requirement to generate OTP.Is it mandatory to store OTP in database or just validate the user givent OTP and process

Comment: What's OTP in this context? What did you try so far?

Comment: Typically OTPs are valid from 5 to 30 minutes. What if your JVM crashes before the OTP expires?

Comment: This is useful info for you: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24092/how-to-store-otp-seed-securely-at-the-validating-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OTP should be stored somewhere for a limited period of time, up to you (and your architecture) to choose if you need to store in a database or in memory using (for example) a password pool.